# Some exceptions are not being caught

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I'm in the process of creating a simple API. I have an `index.php` file which all requests to the API go through. `index.php` processes the parameters of the request to determine which controller and action to use. All of this is wrapped within a `try/catch` block so I can `throw new Exception()` whenever I need to generate an error message for the client side. This has been working as expected, but now I've created a user class that handles user registration and login. Within the registration action, I check if the username passed from the client app already exists in the database, if it does, I `throw new Exception('Username already exists!')`. However, this is not being caught by my `catch`. Instead I'm getting the normal `Fatal error: uncaught exception` message. Here is my code for `index.php`

```
include_once 'models/UserItem.php';

try {

    $enc_request = $_REQUEST['enc_request'];

    $app_id = $_REQUEST['app_id'];
    if( !isset($applications[$app_id]) ) {
      throw new Exception('Application does not exist!');
    }


    $params = json_decode(trim(mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $applications[$app_id], base64_decode($enc_request), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB )));
    if( $params == false || isset($params->controller) == false || isset($params->action) == false ) {
        throw new Exception('Request is not valid');
    }

    $params = (array) $params;

    $controller = ucfirst(strtolower($params['controller'])); //User


    $action = strtolower($params['action']).'Action'; //registerAction

    if( file_exists("controllers/{$controller}.php") ) {
        include_once "controllers/{$controller}.php";
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Controller is invalid.');
    }


    $controller = new $controller($params);

    if( method_exists($controller, $action) === false ) {
        throw new Exception('Action is invalid.');
    }

    $result['data'] = $controller->$action();
    $result['success'] = true;

} catch( Exception $e ) {
    $result = array();
    $result['success'] = false;
    $result['errormsg'] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

The parameters sent to the request are in an array such as:

```
array(
    'controller' => 'user',
    'action' => 'register',
    'username' => $_POST['username'],
    'userpass' => $_POST['userpass']
);
```

The code in `index.php` then calls the `registerAction()` in my `user controller` which is:

```
public function registerAction() {
    $user = new UserItem();
    $user->username = $this->_params['username'];
    $user->password = $this->_params['userpass'];

    $user->user_id = $user->save();

    return $user->toArray();
}
```

This code then calls the method `save` in my `UserItem model` which is:

```
public function save() {
        $db = new Database();
        $db->query('select * from users where username = :user');
        $db->bind(':user', $this->username);
        $r = $db->single();

        if ( $r ) {
            throw new Exception('Username already exists! Please choose another.');
        }

        else {
            $db->query('insert into users(username, password) values(:username, :password)');
            $db->bind(':username', $this->username);
            $db->bind(':password', $this->password);    

            $r = $db->execute();

            $user_array = $this->toArray();

            if ( !$r ) {
                throw new Exception('There was a problem creating your account. Please try again later.');
            }
        }

        return $db->lastInsertId();

}
```

The server is throwing the exception, it's just not being caught properly. Does anyone see anything I've done wrong here in regards to the try/catch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here you thrown an exception but you didn't caught the exception. To implement this , you have to implement inside the try/catch block to handle caught exception. here is an example to implement try it.

```
try{
$user->user_id = $user->save();
}catch(Exception $e){
echo "caught Exception :".$->getMessage();
}
```

i hope it will resolve your problem. thank you.

Comment: if you look a the above code, you'll see that everything is wrapped within a try/catch. So any exceptions that occur down the pipeline should trigger the `catch` right?